# Heat transfer: boundary conditions with fluid velocity

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

The following equation is considered:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - a\Delta u + \mathbf v \cdot \nabla u = f.
$$
I have difficulties in formulating boundary conditions for this equation.
If $\mathbf v$ is absent, the boundary conditions are
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + \beta(u - u_b) = 0
$$
where $u_b$ is prescribed temperature field on the boundary.
But if $\mathbf v$ is present? If we suggest the following boundary condition:
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) + \beta(u - u_b) = 0
$$
then we will have problems with analysing the equation when $(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) > 0$ (where the fluid outflows).
How to set correct boundary conditions?

Comment: I'm no expert here, but I seem to remember just the opposite: if $\mathbf{n}$ is the exterior normal then you just impose zero Neumann BC where $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}\geq 0$, whereas you have to prescribe $a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}+\beta(u-u_b)=F$ for given $F$ where $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}<0$. This makes physical sense to me: in the outflow region the boundary conditions are just self-adjusting to what comes "from the inside", but in the inflow region you have to know what comes from the outside (the PDE cannot know this information). But I have no reference, sorry...

Comment: Just found a reference in my archives: look at [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.20.8990&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and in particular their equation (1.5). I guess the references [5,10] therein should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your second boundary condition is missing a factor $u-u_b$:

$$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - \gamma(u-u_b)(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) + \beta(u - u_b) = 0$$

the coefficient $\beta$ gives the strength of the heat transfer at the boundary; the coefficients $a$ and $\gamma$ are the same as in the diffusion-convection equation,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - a\Delta u + \gamma \mathbf v \cdot \nabla u = f.$$

see, for example, [The convective-diffusion equation and its use in building physics](http://www.bse.polyu.edu.hk/researchCentre/Fire_Engineering/summary_of_output/journal/IJAS/V1/p.68-79.pdf) (2000).

Comment: Thank you! This was a typo. I meant the condition $a\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u + \beta(u - u_b) = 0$.
The heat flux is $\mathbf q = -a\nabla u + \mathbf v u$. Why $(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)(u-u_b)$ instead of $(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u$?

Comment: if the temperature $u$ equals the temperature $u_b$ of the surroundings, there can be no outgoing heat flow, or you'd be violating the second law of thermodynamics...

Comment: In this case we should impose the condition $\beta \geq (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)$. Why is it so (physically)?

Comment: In the case $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)u + \beta(u - u_b)$ there can be outgoing heat flow due to convective transfer ($\mathbf v$), can't it?

Comment: the two terms $a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - \gamma(u-u_b)(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)$ give the _total_ heat transfer across the boundary, due to diffusion (first term) and convection (second term). The boundary condition says that this heat transfer is linearly proportional to the temperature difference at the boundary (Newton's law of heat transfer).

Comment: Reasoning against: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822643/heat-transfer-boundary-conditions-with-fluid-velocity/823290?noredirect=1#comment1702782_823290

Comment: just take $u=u_b$, so no temperature difference between inside and outside at the boundary; you would hope that that then $du/dn=0$ irrespective of $v$, wouldn't you?